# matlab system command with variable

Tags: matlab

i would like to do some process, that will block some IP that stores in variables. The syntax that i wrote:

```
[status4,cmdeks2] = system("sudo tail -1  /var/log/apache2/access.log | cut -d ' ' -f 1");
lm = system(['sudo iptables -A INPUT -s' cmdeks ' -j DROP '])
```

the cmdeks 2 itself is some IP:

```
192.168.88.10
```

But it return some error, that matlab output:

```
/bin/bash : line 1: -j: command not found
```

How do i put that cmdeks in the system syntax?

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is because cmdeks2 contains a line feed code and the iptables command breaks by the line feed code.

[image]

Extracting only IP address via sscanf will work.

```
[status4,cmdeks2] = system("tail -1  ./access.log | cut -d ' ' -f 1");
cmdeks2 = sscanf(cmdeks2, '%s\n'); % cmdeks2 contains only IP address
lm = system(['sudo iptables -A INPUT -s ' cmdeks2 ' -j DROP '])
```

Also, you might have extra iptables rules by your previous trials, so please delete those rules by "iptables -D" command.

Comment: Sounds good! Also, blank space is necessary between -s and cmdeks2, so I've modified a bit.